# Emulate javascript _dopostback in python, web scraping

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize, web-scraping, dopostback

Here [LINK](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#change-value) it is suggested that it is possible to "Figure out what the JavaScript is doing and emulate it in your Python code: " This is what I would like help doing ie my question. How do I emulate javascript:__doPostBack ?

Code from a website (full page source here [LINK](http://pastebin.com/rCBp3G1h):

```
<a style="color: Black;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvSearchResults','Page$2')">2</a>
```

Of course I have basically know idea where to go from here.

Thanks in advance for your help and ideas

Ok there are lots of posts asking how to CLICK a javascript button when web scraping with python libraries mechanize, beautifulsoup....,similar. I see a lot of "that is not supported" responses use THIS non python solution. I think a python solution to this problem would be of great benefit to many. In that light I am not looking for answers like use x,y or z which are not python code or require interacting with a browser.

Comment: You should add links to the text that you are referring to, not LINK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanize page is not suggesting that you can emulate JavaScript in Python. It is saying that you can change a hidden field in a form, thus tricking the web server that a human<sup>[1](http://groups.google.com/group/nzpug/browse_thread/thread/a10538fb635d5786)</sup> has selected the field. You still need to analyse the target yourself.

There will be no Python-based solution to this problem, unless you wish to create a JavaScript interpreter in Python.

[My thoughts](http://groups.google.com/group/nzpug/browse_thread/thread/a10538fb635d5786) on this problem have led me to three possible solutions:

1. create an [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) application
2. browser automation
3. attempt to interpret the client-side code

Of those three, I've only really seen discussion of 2. I've seen something
close to 1 in a commercial scraping application, where you basically create
scripts by browsing on sites and selecting things on the pages that you
would like the script to extract in the future.

1 could possibly made to work with a Python script by accepting a
serialisation (JSON ?) of [wsgi](http://www.wsgi.org/wsgi/What_is_WSGI) Request objects, getting the app to fetch the
URL, then sending the processed page as a wsgi Response object. You could
possibly wrap some middleware around urllib2 to achieve this. Overkill
probably, but kind of fun to think about.

2 is usually achieved via [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) (Remote Control), a testing-centric
tool. It provides a few methods like `getHtmlSource` but most people that I've
heard using it get don't like its API.

3 I have no idea about. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is very hot right now, but I haven't
touched it. I've never been able to build [spidermonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) on my Ubuntu
machine, so I haven't touched that either. My hunch is that in order to do
this, you would provide the HTML source and your details to a JS
interpreter, that would need to fake being your User-Agent etc in case the
JavaScript wanted to reconnect with the server.

<sup>[1](http://groups.google.com/group/nzpug/browse_thread/thread/a10538fb635d5786)</sup> well, more technically, a JavaScript compliant User-Agent, which is almost always a web browser used by a human

Comment: Thanks, for a great explanation of why I can't do it :-) Actually at least now I have a better understanding of the problem. Thanks again.